# Angular cli and teamcity

Tags: angular, teamcity, angular-cli

I need to build and run unittests on my angular 2 project on Teamcity. Locally i'm using angular CLI to build and run unittests and i want to do this on Teamcity as well. I just can not find any documentation for this.

I have made a powershell script which is executed on Teamcity:

```
function runNgBuild() {
    Invoke-Expression Ecgdk.Dealerhub.Client\node_modules\.bin\ng.cmd
}
runNgBuild
```

(This script will be more advanced when i get this simple stuff to work.)

But how do i pass in the process (build, test etc) i want to start?

Comment: did you make any progress on this?  Here is my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168390/ng-e2e-on-teamcity-only-angular-cli-script-that-doesnt-work.  Was hoping maybe you learned something about this by now?